# How to safely delete widget during QDrag execution?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget which lifetime defined by the timer: when the timer expires, widget closes.

This widget has draggable objects which implemented something like this

```
//some code here...

QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
drag->setMimeData(mime);
drag->setPixmap(pixmap);
drag->setHotSpot(hotSpot);
drag->exec();

//some code after...
```

If I start dragging an item, and while in drag, timer expires, it would delete the widget and all it's children, which means all the code after `drag->exec()` wouldn't execute, because the object is already destroyed.

How can I prevent such behaviour, and delete object gracefully?

Comment: Why do you prevent deleting of widget while in a drag? Can't you set a flag before `QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);` which prevents deleting, another flag which is set when timeout wants to delete widget but may not due to first flag, and an evaluation of that 2nd flag after `drag->exec();`?

Comment: The first comment has better solution but you can try to call "QObject::deleteLater()" befole "drag->exec()": http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater. I'm not sure that it is a good solution